# Merge default with user defined settings

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to create a plugin with settings. There will be default settings, and user defined settings. I will have to somehow merge the two in an `object`. I tried the following:

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/er299m6L/)

```js
function MyPlugin(options) {
  if (typeof optoins === null || typeof options !== 'object') options = {};

  var defaults = {
      prop1: true,
      prop2: false,
      prop3: 0,
      prop4: 100,
    }
    // Set default options
  for (var name in defaults) {
    !(name in options) && (this.options[name] = defaults[name]);
  }
}
var test = new MyPlugin();
```

But I get an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop1' of undefined

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `this.options` should probably be `options`. Just like `optoins`. And `typeof` always returns a string, which is `"object"` for `null`.

Comment: `this.options` !== `options`. Also, `typeof optoins === null` makes no sense. Maybe just: `!options || typeof options !== 'object'`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks! I don't quite understand what to do with `this.options !== options`

Comment: The way you are merging the options is OK, but you have to create `this.options` before you start the loop.

Comment: I mean `this.options` is not the same as `options` in your code, it's `undefined`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Oh. I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could be looking at something like this.

```
function MyPlugin(options) {
    options = options || {};

    if (typeof userOpt !== 'object') {
        options = {};
    }

    var defaults = {
        prop1: true,
        prop2: false,
        prop3: 0,
        prop4: 100
    };

    // Set default options
    for (var name in defaults) {
        defaults[name] = options.hasOwnProperty(name) ? options[name] : defaults[name];
    }
}

MyPlugin({
    prop1: false,
    prop4: 300
});
```

So if `MyPlugin()` is called with a `null` then `userOpt` would be an empty object {}.

**Output**:

```
{"prop1":false, "prop2":false, "prop3":0, "prop4":300}
```

The `.hasOwnProperty` is just checking to see if it has been set by the user or not, if yes then go with the user's option otherwise do the default.

**hasOwnProperty**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

> Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method.
>   ***This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object***; unlike the in
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

Comment: The OP's `typeof options !== 'object'` test isn't a bad idea, because the function could be (incorrectly) called with a string or number.

Comment: Make sense, I'll include that check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What's the point of creating a `userOpt`, can't we just use `option`? Something like this: `option = option || {}`

Comment: Was just playing with the code a bit. Yes, it will make the solution even cleaner. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have to create a new `var options`, or could we use the `options` from the argument? Also, one more question.... I was looking around to see how others do this, and I came up with this: https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/Sortable.js#L186 . What's the point of doing `options = _extend({}, options)`? Should I do that too? This tutorial also uses the same logic: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin

Comment: @Jessica oops typo again. `var` shouldn't be there since we are suppose to manipulate the passed in `options` object. I haven't use before the `_extend()` API. I suspect it is a jQuery thing. See -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ but not sure why there isn't a 3rd parameter unless the author is trying abuse the extend API to duplicate the `options` object.

Comment: @SamuelToh So you don't suggest I use that, correct?

Comment: @Jessica Yes. Not recommending it.